# Deleting target with two children

Tags: c++, c, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Would someone mind briefly explaining why I keep getting segmentation faults from this code?

"target" is the Node to be deleted, and I'm trying to replace it with the rightmost leaf on the left branch. "parent" is the parent of target.

```
    else if (target->left != NULL && target->right != NULL) {
      Node * childishDad = target;
      Node * childish = target->left;

      while(childish->right != NULL){
        childishDad = childish;
        childish = childish->right;
      }
      if(parent->left == target)
        parent->left = childish;

      if(parent->right == target)
        parent->right = childish;

      childish->left = target->left;
      childish->right = target->right;

      if(childishDad != target)
        childishDad->right = NULL;

      delete target;
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: Early on, you try to access `childish->right`.  Are you sure that `childish` is not `NULL`?  Has your debugger shown you what line you segfault at?

Comment: @DrewDormann +1 for "Has your debugger shown you what line you segfault at?"

Comment: @DrewDormann, `childish` can't be `NULL`. All assignments to childish are tested for `NULL` before being assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realized that I wasn't checking whether `parent == NULL`, so it was failing in the case where I tried to delete the root node.

Answer (score 0):

When the while-loop completes, you know

```
childish->right == NULL
```

However, later you assign

```
childish->right = target->right;
```

Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I wasn't checking whether parent == NULL, so it was failing in the case where I tried to delete the root node.